# Given two or n texts, how can I measure the degree they are " antithetical", is there any NLP algorithm that can measure this ?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

We are working on a project that aims the polarity in many texts that address the same issue, would you please recommend any useful survey paper/algorithm that can do this ?

Comment: can you clarify what "antithetical" means in your example? if it means one document is positive vs issue and the other negative vs that issue, that would be a sentiment analysis problem. But if it is more specific to the domain, for instance one text approaches a psychological issue in a way which is very different from another text (psychoanalysis vs behaviorism to take an example), then it is a very different problem

Comment: Sounds like you need two things: Topic detection (easier when you have a fixed list of topics you are matching against, harder if open-ended) and sentiment analysis so you can detect opposing positions when the topic is the same.